# PHP Search Form doesn't return all the results

Tags: php, odbc

I have a vehicle dealership website. This website draws the vehicle information from an Access database (.mdb). I can't change this as the integration is coming from their current DMS which saves the data to an .mdb.

On this website, I have a search form to query the database for specific vehicles. The form works, and so does the query.

But, here's problem; say for instance there are 5 Ford cars in the database, and the user searches for all the available Fords, the query only returns 4 of the available 5.

Please see my code below.

```
        $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", '', '');

        $searchMake = addslashes($_POST['makeSelection']);
        $searchModel = addslashes($_POST['modelSelection']);
        $searchBranch = addslashes($_POST['branchSelection']);
        $searchYear = addslashes($_POST['yearSelection']);
        $minPrice = addslashes($_POST['minPriceSelection']);
        $maxPrice = addslashes($_POST['maxPriceSelection']);

        $sql = "SELECT Id, Make, Model, Year, Price, SpecialPrice, Branch, StockNO FROM Vehicle";

        if ($searchMake || $searchBranch || $minPrice || $maxPrice) {
            $sql .= "WHERE ";
        }

        $combine = '';

        if ($minPrice) {
            $sql .="{$combine}Price BETWEEN $minPrice "; $combine = 'BETWEEN ';
        }

        if ($maxPrice) {
            $sql .="AND $maxPrice "; $combine = 'AND ';
        }

        if ($searchMake) {
            $sql .="{$combine}Make LIKE '%$searchMake%' "; $combine = 'AND ';
        }

        if ($searchBranch) {
            $sql .="{$combine}Branch LIKE '%$searchBranch%' ";
        }

        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

        if (odbc_num_rows( $rs ) == -1) {

            echo "We don’t have the vehicle you are looking for right now, but send us your vehicle requirements and we will be sure to find you one!";

        } else {

            echo "\t" . "<tr>\n";

            echo "\t" . "<th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th><th>Special Price</th><th>Location</th><th>Stock Number</th>" . "\n";

            while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) { 
                $id = odbc_result($rs, Id);
                $make = odbc_result($rs, Make);
                $model = odbc_result($rs, Model);
                $year = odbc_result($rs, Year);
                $price = odbc_result($rs, Price);
                $specialPrice = odbc_result($rs, SpecialPrice);
                $branch = odbc_result($rs, Branch);
                $stockNo = odbc_result($rs, StockNO);

                echo "\t" . "<tr>\n";
                echo "\t\t" . "<td><a href=/selected-vehicles?Id=$id>" . $make . "</td><td><a href=/selected-vehicles?Id=$id>" . $model . "</a></td><td>" . $year . "</td><td>" . $price . "</td><td>" . $specialPrice . "</td><td>" . $branch . "</td><td>" . $stockNo . "</td>\n";

                echo "\t" . "</tr>\n";
            }

        }

      odbc_free_result($rs);
      odbc_close($conn);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You checked if $searchMake $searchBranch $minPrice and $maxPrice are really false?

Comment: if (odbc_fetch_row($rs) === TRUE) { I am not 100% sure but I think you are fetching the first entry here already. So the first entry is already fetched and you always have 1 entry less

Comment: You should try to delete that if statement and check if it works then!

Comment: That if statement is there so that when the query can't find something, you get the message saying that the query came up empty.

Comment: Yea, but I think that fetches the first row already but is Not using the result. just TRY to delete it for once and check if it works.

Comment: So I did as you said @Xatenev and you're right. It works when I remove that if statement.

Comment: I have wrote an answer on this, which solves your problem aswell as giving you the check for empty or not

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
  if (odbc_fetch_row($rs) === TRUE) {
```

You are already fetching the first entry here but you are NOT using the result..

Use this to check if its empty or not:

```
if(odbc_num_rows( $rs ) == 0){
        // when no result
} else {
        // when result
}
```

Comment: See, this works, but now the else statement isn't executing. I mean, the message if the desired vehicle couldn't be found doesn't show. Please see my updated code...

Comment: @deon4110 Ah probably you just have to check for true or false, check my updated answer. I deleted the !== 0. Because odbc_num_rows can return 0, false or -1. That will all evaluate to false so this should work now!

Comment: It worked for me... Try to check against "-1" like if(xxx == -1) {...}

Comment: Yeah, that works to display the message. Now all it does is display the message even if the vehicle is available.

Comment: Can you var_dump($rs); and check what you get when you have 0 results.

Comment: This is the output... `resource(335) of type (odbc result) `

Comment: Ah ok. I have just read a question on stackoverflow having the same problem -> There is no way to check if its empty with odbc driver. Check this solution for that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295507/php-oracle-and-odbc-how-to-check-if-result-set-is-empty